# What does the limit $\lim_{x \to a}\frac{(x-a)f'(x)}{f(x)}$ mean for non-polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

The limit $$\lim_{x \to a}\frac{(x-a)f'(x)}{f(x)}$$
has an important meaning for polynomials. Suppose $f(x)=(x-a)^nq(x)$ where $q(a)\neq 0$. Then, the given limit is equivalent to
$$\lim_{x \to a}\frac{\{n(x-a)^{n-1}q(x)+(x-a)^nq'(x)\}(x-a)}{(x-a)^nq(x)}=\lim_{x \to a}\frac{nq(x)+(x-a)q'(x)}{q(x)}=n+\lim_{x \to a}\frac{(x-a)q'(x)}{q(x)}=n$$
where the last limit comes from the fact that $q(a)\neq 0$, but the numerator goes to zero. So, for polynomials, the value of the given limit would indicate the algebraic multiplicity of the polynomial of the term $(x-a)$. We could also extend this concept to functions not quite polynomial, but "looks" like a polynomial, for example functions like $x-4\sqrt{x}+3$. This function has the above limit value when $a=1$ as
$$\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{(x-1)\times \{1-\frac{2}{\sqrt{x}}\}}{(\sqrt{x}-1)(\sqrt{x}-3)}=\frac{2\cdot (-1)}{1-3}=1$$
One could also extend to functions like $f(x)=x^\pi$. The limit in this case would be,
$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x\times \pi x^{\pi-1}}{x^\pi}=\pi$$
So, the limit would similarly be the value of the "degree of $(x-a)$"(which, if it is even a valid saying).

(Note that we choose function $f(x)$ and the value $a$ for each limit. Yet since the limit has some meaning when $f(a)=0$, I would omit the choice of $a$ whenever the root of $f(x)$ is unique.)

My question is, how can I extend this concept to functions that are **not** in the form of $f(x^p)$(where $f$ is a polynomial, $p$ is a real number)? Are there any meaning to this limit value when the function is a transcendental function? Are there any concepts that this value represents?

---

(Edit) Here are some examples of the value of the limit for some functions.

- $f(x)=e^{-x}(x^3\sin x)$ at $a=0$ $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{xf'(x)}{f(x)}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x\times e^{-x}(-x^3\sin x+3x^2\sin x+x^3\cos x)}{e^{-x}(x^3\sin x)}=4$$
- $f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x}$ at $a=0$ $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{xf'(x)}{f(x)}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x\times \frac{x\cos x-\sin x}{x^2}}{\frac{\sin x}{x}}=0$$
- $f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x}$ at $a=\pi$ $$\lim_{x \to \pi}\frac{(x-\pi)f'(x)}{f(x)}=\lim_{x \to \pi}\frac{(x-\pi)\frac{x \cos x-\sin x}{x^2}}{\frac{\sin x}{x}}=1$$
- $f(x)=e^x-1$ at $a=0$ $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{xf'(x)}{f(x)}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x\times e^x}{e^x-1}=1$$

Comment: We also have $\lim_{x \to a} \frac{\log |f(x)|}{\log |x-a|}$. If $f$ is differentiable at $a$, this is equal by L'Hopital's rule.

Answer (score 3):

If $\ f\ $ is at least $\ n\ $ times continuously differentiable in a neighbourhood of $\ a\ $, $\ f^{(n)}(a)\ne0$$\,\ $, and $\ f^{(k)}(a)=0\ $ for all $\ k\le n-1\ $, then by [Taylor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem) with Lagrange form of remainder,
\begin{align}
f(x)&=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{(x-a)^if^{(i)}(a)}{i!}+\frac{(x-a)^nf^{(n)}(\xi)}{n!}\\
&=\frac{(x-a)^nf^{(n)}(\xi)}{n!}\\
f'(x)&=\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}\frac{(x-a)^if^{(i+1)}(a)}{i!}+\frac{(x-a)^nf^{(n)}(\eta)}{(n-1)!}\\
&=\frac{(x-a)^nf^{(n)}(\eta)}{(n-1)!}\ ,
\end{align}
where $\ a\le\xi,\eta\le x\ $ or $\ x\le\xi,\eta\le a\ $.  It follows that for any such $\ f\ $
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{(x-a)f'(x)}{f(x)}=n\ .
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have a few questions though. Isn't $n$ the **largest** value of $k$ such that $f^{(k)}(a)\neq 0$? Also, the approach assumes that $n$ is a natural number, which is not the case for some cases such as $x^\pi$.

Comment: No, it's one plus the largest value of $\ k\ $ for which $\ f^{(k)}(a)=0\ $ or $0$ if $\ f(a)=0\ $, or, equivalently, the smallest value of $\ k\ $ for which $\ f^{(k)}(a)\ne0\ $. As long as $\ f\ $ is continuously differentiable sufficiently many times in a neighbourhood of $\ a\ $, then the largest value of $\ k\ $ for which $\ f^{k}(a)\ne0\ $ *must* be an integer, and the result will hold.

Comment: If $\ f(x)=x^\pi=e^{\pi\ln x}\ $, for instance, then $\ f $ is infinitely continuously differentiable and $\ f'(x)=$$\pi x^{\pi-1}\ne0\ $ for $\ x>0\ $ and , so the result tells you that $\ \lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{(x-a)f'(x)}{f(x)}=0\ $.

Comment: But isn't the limit $\pi$?

Comment: $\ \lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{\pi x^{\pi-1}}{x^\pi}=\frac{\pi}{a}\ $, but $\ \lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{{\color{red}{(x-a)}}f'(x)}{f(x)}=0\ $

Comment: We have $a=0$ in this case. We can choose the value of $a$ and the function $f(x)$ for each limit. Maybe my words were misleading. I’ll edit it.

Comment: $\ x^\pi\ $ isn't continuously differentiable at $\ x=0\ $, so the result won't hold for $\ a=0\ $.  My previous two comments only apply for $\ a>0\ $

Comment: Is it because the function is not defined at $x<0$? Then what happens if I just consider the right hand side limit as definition? So, just $\lim_{x \to a+}\frac{(x-a)f'(x)}{f(x)}$ where $a=0$ and $f(x)=x^\pi$.

Comment: The function $\ f(x)=x^\pi\ $ is twice differentiable from the right at $\ x=0\ $, with $\ f(0)=f^{(1)}(0)=f^{(2)}(0)=0\ $, but $\ \lim_\limits{x\rightarrow0^+}\frac{(\pi-1)(\pi-2)x^{\pi-3}}{x}\ $ does not exist, so it's not three times differentiable from the right at $\ x=0\ $.  So even if these were two-sided derivatives, the conditions necessary for the result to hold would not be satisfied.

Answer (score 2):

Remark: This is more a long comment than an answer.

> the limit would similarly be the value of the "degree of $(x−a)$"

This would be usually called the *multiplicity* of $a$ as a zero of $f$. For polynomial, the multiplicity is a nonnegative integer, but your definition could be used to defined non-integer multiplicity.

> Are there any meaning to this limit value when the function is a transcendental function?

This is a huge simplification but, in general, we can define whatever we want, the important question being "is it useful?" which can be split into two important questions:

1. Does it have interesting properties?
2. Does it solve important problems?

Consider the first question: let $\mu_a(f)$ be the limit $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{(x-a)f'(x)}{f(x)}$. I think it would be fair to call $\mu_a$ multiplicity of $a$ as a zero of $f$ if it satisfies the two properties the multiplicities of zeros of polynomials:

1. $\mu_{a}(fg)=\mu_a(f)+\mu_a(g)$
2. $\mu_a(f+g)\ge Min(\mu_{a}(f),\mu_a(g))$

(First one is a consequence of the Product Rule, I didn't check the second).

I add a third property, true for polynomials when $n$ is a integer:
3. $\mu_{a}((x-a)^n)=n$ for every real numbers $a$ and $n$.

If Properties 1,2, and 3 are satisfied, I think it is not a bad idea to call $\mu_a$ *multiplicity* (or *generalized multiplicity* or *Woo multiplicity*) and continue its study

Note that the notion of multiplicity can be extended to functions that are analytic at $a$ (this includes polynomials):

> Let $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(x-a)^n$. Then $a$ is a zero of $f$ of multiplicity $m$ if and only if $a_0=a_1=\dots=a_{m=1}=0$ and $a_m\neq 0$.

The theorem for the derivative of power series implies that $\mu_a(f)=m$ in this case.

Note: I have no idea whether $\mu_a$ has been already studied and has interesting applications or not.

Comment: Thanks for the answer sir. I will check the second property of multiplicity.

Answer (score 1):

3 cases.

Case 1, $f(a) \ne 0$
Case 2, $f(a) = 0$ and $f'(a) \ne 0$
Case 3, $f(a) = 0$, and $f'(a) = 0$

Case 1

$f'(a) = \lim_\limits{x\to a} \frac {f(x) - f(a)}{x-a}$

$\lim_\limits{x\to a} \frac {(x-a)f'(x)}{f(x)} = \frac {(x-a)(f(x)-f(a))}{(x-a)f(x)} = 0$

Case 2

$\lim_\limits{x\to a} \frac {(x-a)f'(x)}{f(x)} = \lim_\limits{x\to a}\frac {(x-a)(f'(x))}{f(x)-f(a)} = \lim_\limits{x\to a}\frac {f'(x)}{f'(a)}= 1$

Case 3 makes what is above indeterminate, and the limit may take on other values